# FitNesse: Test that an element is not in a list?

Tags: testing, fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm using [FitSharp](http://www.syterra.com/FitSharp.html) to test an application and have a question related to testing contents of lists. Testing that an element is present in a list is simple to do using, for example, a [SubsetFixture](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitLibraryUserGuide.SubsetFixture) and could be written as this:

```
| Check that element is in list |
| 5 |
```

But is there a way to write a fixture that tests if an element is *not* in a list?

```
| Check that element is not in list |
| 5 |
```

I want the last table to pass only if 5 is not in the processed list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can come with any kind of list fixture would be to use a array or set fixture and to list ALL of the items you DO expect. There is no "not one of these" list fixtures.

I would recommend you just do a do fixture in one like like:

```
|check|that element | 5 |  is in the list | False |
```

or you could use a column fixture to get the feel for a set fixture

```
| Check that element is not in list |
| element | exists? |
| 5 | false |
```

Comment: This is what I would recommend.

Comment: We have gone for a solution like this one too since it seems to be the only reasonable. I stated my original question unclearly, because we can have more complex objects than integers in the lists, but I think we can manage that somehow, should the problem arise.